# How to change the status bar background color on iOS 7?

Tags: ios7, statusbar

My current application runs on iOS 4.2, 5 and 6.

The navigation bar is having an orange color and the status bar is having a black background color . However, when I run the same application on iOS 7, I observe the status bar looks transparent with the same orange background color as the navigation bar.

Due to this I'm not able to differentiate between the status bar and the navigation bar.
How do I make the status bar to look the same as it was in iOS 5 and 6, that is with black background color and white text color? How can I do this programmatically?

I searched about this on google and found a suggestion that I've to add a black colour background, about 20 pix high view that overlaps the status bar to provide a black background view. I tried it out but was unsuccessful.

Could someone provide me with the code to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

try to call below function in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`
It worked for me

```
func setStatusBarBackgroundColor(color: UIColor) {

guard  let statusBar = UIApplication.sharedApplication().valueForKey("statusBarWindow")?.valueForKey("statusBar") as? UIView else {
    return
}

statusBar.backgroundColor = color
}
```

In swift

If working in objective C, then try this:

```
- (void)setStatusBarBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)color {

UIView *statusBar = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBarWindow"] valueForKey:@"statusBar"];

if ([statusBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:)]) {
    statusBar.backgroundColor = color;
}
}
```

Hope it will helps others, as question posted many years ago. :)